# C++ Linked List Not Preserving New Nodes

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to transition from an almost entirely Java background to getting comfortable with C++. I'm practicing by trying to build a basic Linked List.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string data;
    node *next = NULL;
};

class linkedlist
{
    public:
    node *head;

    public:
    linkedlist()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    void addNode(string s)
    {
        node *newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = s;

        if(head == NULL)
            head = newNode;

        else
        {
            node *temp = head->next;

            while(temp != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;

            temp = newNode;
        }
    }

    void printList()
    {
        node *temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << '\n';

            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
};
```

The issue at hand is that once I add a new node using `void addNode(string s)`, it does not appear when I attempt to print the list (starting from the head) with `void printList()`.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    string str;
    linkedlist list;

    cout << "Please enter the number of strings you'd like to enter:\n";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        string temp;

        cout << "Enter string #" << i + 1 << '\n';
        cin >> temp;

        list.addNode(temp);
    }

    cout << "This is your linked list: ";

    list.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Using main() above, my results become:

> This is your linked list:
>   (string 1)

I'm pretty certain I'm using pointers improperly here but I don't see why. I've done as much digging as I can on my own for some clarification on how I could be doing this wrong but I'm coming up blank.

Thanks for any clarification you folks can provide.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the program.  Trying to guess as to the issue won't get you too far.  As to this: `temp = newNode;` -- this is not like Java.  The `temp` is not a reference to the previous `temp->next` -- it is its own value.  Assigning to it only affects `temp`, no other pointers.  You need to change directly `temp->next`.  Maybe that's why you were confused -- thinking that C++ is reference-based, like Java.

Comment: You are not setting the `next` field of your nodes.  You may want to try something like `temp.next = newNode;`.  When debugging linked lists, draw as you single step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        node *temp = head->next;

        while(temp != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;

        temp = newNode;
```

You're traversing the list, then setting `temp` to the value of the `newNode`.  When `temp` goes out of scope, the value for `newNode` isn't stored anyplace.

What you want to do is set the `next` pointer of the last `node` to the value of `newNode`, i.e.

```
        node *temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = newNode;
```

The code above traverses the list until it finds a `node` that doesn't have a `next` node, and sets its `next` node to the `newNode`, thus adding it to the list.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps clarify pointers for me. Much appreciated!